# how to get the new latitudes and longitudes while moving Using Xcode

Tags: xcode6

I am developing an App that records the latitude and longitudes  for every 10mts  and save them in server , so  far I am able to  get the current location of the person but the values are not changing, I used timers too
     below is my code

```
//  FamilyTrackerViewController.m
//  FamilyTracker
//
//  Created by Osmosys on 03/02/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Osmosys. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FamilyTrackerViewController.h"

@interface FamilyTrackerViewController ()

@end

@implementation FamilyTrackerViewController
@synthesize CLController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated:(BOOL)animated
{

CLController = [[OSMGPSLocationTrackingDelegate alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    _txtMobileNumber.delegate=self;
    double score = xxxxxxxx429;
   // NSString *str=@"xxxxxx429";

    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithString:str] forKey:@"HIGHSCORE"];
  //  str=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HIGHSCORE"] stringValue];
//     score = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HIGHSCORE"] doubleValue];
    _txtMobileNumber.text= @"XXXXXX429";


#pragma mark NextPrevios Methods

    UIToolbar *objToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    // objToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];



 //   [objToolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigations_iPhone.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    //  [objToolbar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigations_iPhone.png"]] atIndex:0];

    // objToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    UIBarButtonItem *objBarbtndone=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    //  objBarbtndone.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    objBarbtndone.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    objBarbtndone.title=@"Done";
    objBarbtndone.target=self;
    objBarbtndone.action=@selector(btnBarDone);

    UIBarButtonItem *objBarbtnPre=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    objBarbtnPre.title=@"Previous";
    // objBarbtnPre.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    objBarbtnPre.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    objBarbtnPre.target=self;
    objBarbtnPre.action=@selector(btnBarPre);


    UIBarButtonItem *objBarbtnNext=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    // objBarbtnNext.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    objBarbtnNext.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    objToolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    objBarbtnNext.title=@"Next";
    objBarbtnNext.target=self;
    objBarbtnNext.action=@selector(btnBtnNxt);


    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue]<7.0)
    {



        objBarbtnNext.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        objBarbtnPre.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        objBarbtndone.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];




    }

    UIBarButtonItem *objBarbtnSpace= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    objToolbar.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objBarbtnPre,objBarbtnNext,objBarbtnSpace,objBarbtndone, nil];


     _txtMobileNumber.inputAccessoryView=objToolbar;

 //CLController = [[OSMGPSLocationTrackingDelegate alloc] init];
   //CLController.delegate = self;
//[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:2.0];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(useLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)useLocation{
    NSLog(@"%@",[locationManager location]);
    //CLController = [[OSMGPSLocationTrackingDelegate alloc] init];
   // CLController.delegate = self;
   // [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];



    locationManager1 = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager1 setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager1 setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager1 setDistanceFilter:2.0];
    [locationManager1 startUpdatingLocation];


    _lbllogitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.18f",locationManager1.location.coordinate.longitude];
   _lblLatitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.18f",locationManager1.location.coordinate.latitude];
    [locationManager1 stopUpdatingLocation];


}


-(void)btnBarDone
{
    [_txtMobileNumber resignFirstResponder];
}



//Loading the GPS location data to the apps loclable string
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    locLabel= [location description];
    _lbllogitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.15f",location.coordinate.longitude];
    _lblLatitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.15f",location.coordinate.latitude];


   // _lbllogitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
  //  _lblLatitudes.text=  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];

}

//If any error occurs.
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    locLabel = [error description];
    //[self.GPSOutput setText:locLabel];
}
//Closing the GPS device and service.
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //Stoping the GPS data
    [CLController.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `CLLocationManager`'s delegate:

`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

you will get an array of `CLLocation`, just extract your current coordinate from its last object.

You don't need timer, the delegate will automatically send location updates to you.

Comment: How can i draw a polyline between two cordinates ?